# In context of MSSM, what is stop mixing?

Tags: supersymmetry, quarks, mssm

In context of MSSM, what is [stop mixing](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=susy&as_epq=stop+mixing) and stop mixing parameter?

Comment: Perhaps you can let us know what you already know about this so that we don't tell what you don't need to know.

Comment: I know nothing on this and never find explanations for  beginner in any book. The answer given below looks extremely interesting. I investigate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squarks can be written in terms of their left and right components - gauge eigenstates, if you will. Similar to the [distinction between flavour and mass eigenstates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontecorvo%E2%80%93Maki%E2%80%93Nakagawa%E2%80%93Sakata_matrix) for neutrinos, these gauge eigenstates are different from the mass eigenstates for the stop and sbottom - in other words, the [mass matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_matrix) is not diagonal (whereas for the other squarks the off-diagonal components of the mass matrix are approximately 0). When we diagonalise this mass matrix using an unitary transformation, we obtain the mass eigenbasis for the stop and sbottom. The stop mass eigenbasis is then a rotated version of the gauge eigenbasis - this is stop mixing.

The contribution to stop mass comes from four sources (ignoring for now their RG evolution):

| Name | Term |
| --- | --- |
| ordinary mass terms | $\tilde t^*_L\tilde t_L=m^2_{\tilde t_L}+\Delta_{\tilde t_L}$ |
| quartic F-terms | $\tilde t^*_L y_t^2\tilde t_L|\langle H^0_u\rangle|^2=m^2_t$ |
| $\mu-$ and superYukawa F-terms | $\mu^*\tilde t^*_R y_t\tilde t_L\langle H^0_d\rangle$ + c.c. |
| soft SUSY breaking terms | $\tilde t^*_R a_t\tilde t_L\langle H^0_u\rangle$ + c.c. |

It is the latter two off-diagonal contributions that are responsible for the disparity between gauge and mass eigenstates for stops. Note that these terms can be complex in the case of complex $\mu$. The overall mass matrix is thus
$$
M^2_{\tilde t}=\pmatrix{m^2_{LL} & m^2_{LR}\\m^2_{RL} & m^2_{RR}}=\pmatrix{m^2_{\tilde t_L}+m^2_t+\Delta_{\tilde t_L} & m_t(a_t-\mu\cot\beta)\\
m_t(a_t-\mu^*\cot\beta)& m^2_{\tilde t_R}+m^2_t+\Delta_{\tilde t_R}
}
$$

For reference, $\tan\beta = \frac{\langle H_u\rangle}{\langle H_d\rangle}$, $\Delta_i=m_Z^2\cos2\beta\left(T^3_i-\sin^2\theta_W\ Y_i\right)$, $m_t$ is the top quark mass, $a_t$ is the [soft SUSY breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_SUSY_breaking) parameter for the top system and $\mu$ is the coefficient of the Higgs mass term in the [superpotential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpotential).

Finally we transform the overall mass term by diagonalising the mass matrix with an appropriate unitary matrix $U$:
$$
U = \pmatrix{e^{i\phi}\cos\theta_{\tilde t} & \sin\theta_{\tilde t}\\ -\sin\theta_{\tilde t} & e^{-i\phi}\cos\theta_{\tilde t}}
\\\Rightarrow\pmatrix{\tilde t_L\\\tilde t_R}^\dagger M_{\tilde t}^2 \pmatrix{\tilde t_L\\\tilde t_R}
\\=\underbrace{\pmatrix{\tilde t_L\\\tilde t_R}^\dagger U^\dagger}_{\pmatrix{\tilde t_1\\\tilde t_2}^\dagger}\; \underbrace{U M_{\tilde t}^2 U^\dagger}_{\mathbf M^2_{\tilde t}}\; \underbrace{U \pmatrix{\tilde t_L\\\tilde t_R}}_{\pmatrix{\tilde t_1\\\tilde t_2}}
\\\mathbf M^2_{\tilde t}=U M_{\tilde t}^2 U^\dagger = \pmatrix{m^2_{\tilde t_1} & 0\\0 & m^2_{\tilde t_2}}
\\\pmatrix{\tilde t_1\\\tilde t_2} = U \pmatrix{\tilde t_L\\\tilde t_R}
\\
$$
$\tilde t_L$ and $\tilde t_R$ mix to form the mass eigenstates $\tilde t_1$ and $\tilde t_2$, with $m^2_{\tilde t_1} < m^2_{\tilde t_2}$. As a result, $\theta_{\tilde t}$ is called the *stop mixing angle* and the phase $\phi$ is $\mathrm{Arg}\ M^2_{LR}$. Many supersymmetric extensions of the Standard Model predict that $\tilde t_1$ is in fact the lightest squark after RG flowing down to the EW scale.